# How to add merge fields related to User and Community in Lightning Email Template

Tags: lightning-experience, user, merge-field, lightning-email-template

I've created a Lightning Email Template where i have to add merge fields related to user and community but there are no such merge fields in merge field picker

I want to add

- `{!Community.Url}`
- `{!Community_Name}`
- `{!Receiving_User.Username}`

Is there limitations on merge field values for Lightning Email Templates?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.merge_fields_communities.htm&type=5),

> To insert merge fields into your Experience Cloud site email templates,
>
> 1. From Setup, enter Email Templates in the Quick Find box, and select
>    Classic Email Templates. Next to an email template, click Edit.
> 2. Under Available Merge Fields, from the dropdown menu, select the field
>    type, and then select the field. For merge fields specific to sites,
>    select Network Member Fields.
> 3. Copy the merge field value into the body of the email template.

There is no mention of Lightning email templates and so it looks like community merge fields are not supported yet.

Also see [known issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001JlzmQAC) according to which the workaround listed is

> The option to use these template types is not fully supported for Site (Community) emails. Please use Classic templates if using merge fields is required for the emails intended purposes.